# date formatting in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date-format, date

this query:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'Ddspth MONTH, Yyyysp') from dual
```

will return:

```
Eighteenth MARCH , Two Thousand Fourteen
```

i am wondering if there are any additional formatting keywords that will allow including a list of characters like "of" , "the" ... inorder to have an output like:

```
"Today is the" Eighteenth "of" MARCH, Two Thousand Fourteen
```

or is that requires splitting the date conversion and using a concat function? thanks

for example :

```
select 'Today is the ' || to_char(sysdate, 'Ddspth') || ' of' || to_char(sysdate,' MONTH, Yyyysp') from dual
```

Comment: You'll have to concatenate.

Comment: @Phil it is actually possible...see my answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

figured this out, here is a solution in case someone needs to do something similar...

using double quotes "" around characters will display them as they are...

```
select to_char(sysdate,'"Today is the" Ddspth "of" fmMONTH,Yyyysp') as Today from dual
```

will display:

```
"Today is the" Eighteenth "of" MARCH, Two Thousand Fourteen
```

Comment: Excellent find. Couldn't see that in the docs anywhere.

Comment: @joe: the manual page: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA